# Complex pattern rule in Makefile

Tags: makefile

I have the following makefile I use to generate files from some templates, the generated files have two possible extensions:

```
%.tex: %.tex*_tpl
    ./generate $@_tpl -o $@

%.xml: %.xml*_tpl
    ./generate $@_tpl -o $@
```

The dependency list will here match things like `a.tex_tpl`, `a.tex-subpart1_tpl`, `a.tex-subpart2_tpl`.

While this works, is there a way to avoid repetition? For example by matching `*.{tex,xml}` in the rule name and use the whole matched name in the dependency list? Something that would look like that:

```
%.{tex,xml}: $@_tpl
    ./generate $< -o $@
```

(Though I know `%.{tex,xml}` is not a valid rule name and you can't use `$@` in the dependency list)

Or any other (cleaner?) way.

Comment: I can't think of anything that would make this much cleaner, although it depends on what you mean by "cleaner".  You can put the recipe into a variable: `GENERATE = ./generate $@_tpl -o $@` then use the `$(GENERATE)` variable in each command; that would reduce the number of places you needed to update the recipe.

Comment: It's better indeed, thanks! I don't really know what I'd call "cleaner", I can only think of some vague descriptions like "short and not hacky".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Seems to me this does what you are looking for:

```
#
# I've assumed that files of the form:
#
#  a.xml_tpl
#  b.tex_tpl
#
# determine what targets you want to build
#
TARGETS:=$(patsubst %_tpl,%,$(wildcard *.xml_tpl *.tex_tpl))

.PHONY: all
all: $(TARGETS)

.SECONDEXPANSION:
$(TARGETS): %: $$(wildcard %*_tpl)
    ./generate $^ -o $@
```

The key is to use [`.SECONDEXPANSION`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Secondary-Expansion.html) to allow `$$(wildcard %*_tpl)` to be evaluated in a second expansion phase. The double `$` is not a typo, by the way; it protects the expression from being evaluated at the time of the first expansion.

If I populate a directory with these files:

```
a.tex-subpart1_tpl
a.tex_tpl
a.xml-subpart1_tpl
a.xml-subpart2_tpl
a.xml_tpl
```

and run `make -n`, I get this on the console:

```
./generate a.xml_tpl a.xml-subpart1_tpl a.xml-subpart2_tpl -o a.xml
./generate a.tex_tpl a.tex-subpart1_tpl -o a.tex
```

#### Why the Second Expansion?

Without the second expansion, you'd have to have `$(wildcard %*_tpl)` in the dependency because with the `$$` the wildcard function would never execute. Instead, make would treat `$$(wildcard..)` *literally* as the dependency, which is obviously wrong.

Ok, so `$(wildcard %*_tpl)` would be evaluated at the time make first runs across that line (this is the "first expansion"). *At that time* `%` has no value yet so `wildcard` would roughly be doing something like what would be `ls %*_tpl` at the command line.

For reasons of speed, make does not by default give you the opportunity to do any evaluation later than during the first expansion. If you want a later opportunity you have to specify `.SECONDEXPANSION`, which turns on the second expansion processing. Make still performs the firts expansion as usual. This is why you need to have `$$(wildcard`: it is transformed to `$(wildcard` during the first expansion. At the time of the second expansion make sees `$(wildcard %*_tpl)`, *replaces `%` with the actual stem* and then executes the `wildcard` function with the actual stem rather than with a literal `%`.

#### Why `$(TARGETS)` in the Pattern Rule?

The pattern rule could be written:

```
%: $$(wildcard %*_tpl)
    ./generate $^ -o $@
```

without `$(TARGETS)`. However, this rule would do nothing, as it would be a ["match-anything rule"](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Match_002dAnything-Rules.html). Basically, if make took such a rule at face value, then the computation cost would be significant, and most likely it is not the case that the author of the `Makefile` *really* means to apply this rule to *any* file whatsoever. So such a rule comes with restrictions, which in the Makefile here make it useless.

Adding `$(TARGETS)` makes it into a [static pattern rule](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Static-Pattern.html#index-static-pattern-rule), which is not a match-anything rule. The addition of `$(TARGETS)` in front of the target pattern tells make that the rule applies only to *these* targets, and nothing else.

Comment: That may qualify as "hacky" :D but it sounds great! I have no more time to test it today but I'll get back to you as soon as I do, thanks! EDIT: and the comment at the beginning of your makefile is right, sorry if I was unclear. The only thing that differ is that the `generate` script only take one file (`$@_tpl`) as input, and this file has instructions (jinja's `include`) to include others (the `-subpart_tpl` ones) but that shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: This isn't *cleaner* except to a GNU Make guru.

Comment: I actually really like it, especially the fact that it generate a list of available targets by looking at what `_tpl` files are there. I don't need to limitate those targets to xml and tex files by the way so I can even shorten it to `TARGETS:=$(patsubst %_tpl,%,$(wildcard *_tpl))`. I have two questions though: 1) What makes `.SECONDEXPANSION` mandatory? Is it the `wildcard` function that must be expanded *after* the `%` expansion? 2) I failed to find documentation about the extra `: %:` in the `$(TARGETS)` rule, what is it? (I guess it creates a pattern rule from a list of target?).

Comment: @Dettorer Without the second expansion, you'd put `$(wildcard %*_tpl)` because with the `$$` the `wildcard` function would never execute. Now `$(wildcard %*_tpl)` would be evaluated at the time make *first* runs across that line. *At that time* `%` has no value *yet* so `wildcard` would roughly be doing something like what would be`ls %*_tpl` at the command line. At the time of the second expansion, `%` is replaced with an actual stem and *then* `wildcard` is exectued.

Comment: @Louis Thanks, that's what I (vaguely) thought. What is the extra '%:' after '$(TARGETS):' though? Where is it documented? (or what is the name of the concept?)

Comment: Ah, I found it, a [static pattern rule](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Static-Pattern).

Comment: @Dettorer yes, that's what it is. I'm in the process of editing my answer to add this kind of information.

Comment: @Louis That's a useful edit, thanks! I think the first paragraph of **`Why the Second Expansion?`** is a bit confusing though: explaining that `.SECONDEXPANSION` is needed *because* of the `$$` is weird, since no one would ask about `.SECONDEXPANSION` while knowing the meaning of `$$` (and by that I mean "without thinking it's just an escaped `$`"). Apart from that, the explanations are fairly clear, useful and provide links to the documentation so thanks!