# Directory independent target in Makefile

Tags: makefile

I'm trying to make a rule that will generate files regarding their names but regardless of the directory.

I'm starting from this makefile (see [a previous question of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26672148/complex-pattern-rule-in-makefile/26679394#26679394)):

```
TARGETS:=$(patsubst %_tpl,%,$(wildcard *_tpl))

.PHONY: all
all: $(TARGETS)

.SECONDEXPANSION:
$(TARGETS): %: $$(wildcard %*_tpl)
    ./generate $@_tpl > $@
```

With this, I can do, for instance, `make foo.xml`. It looks if a set of `foo.xml*_tpl` files are there, consider them as prerequisites and call the `generate` script to generate the target.

What I would like to do is, for example, `make ../ressources/foo.xml` and have make use the rule to create `foo.xml` but creating it in the `../ressources/` directory, without having to explicitely specify this directory in the makefile.

What I have tried for the moment is adding this to the Makefile:

```
../ressources/%: $(notdir %)
    mv $< $@
```

Which works, but I would like to avoid creating the file in the current directory before moving it to the destination folder. I would also like not having to specify the possible destination folders in the makefile (but this is less important).

But first of all, does this make any sense? Or is what I want to do just conceptually wrong?

**EDIT:** Some precisions regarding the `_tpl` files and the `generate` script to avoid confusions:

Each target has a main template (`$@_tpl`) that includes others (`$@-part1_tpl`, `$@-part2_tpl`...) and the `generate` script only takes the main template as argument. The templates are written with Jinja2 (the subparts included with the `{% include %}` jinja directive).

Comment: Are the files needed to create `foo.xml` also supposed to be in the same directory as `foo.xml` itself? And `bar.xml` could be in a different directory but would have its dependencies in the same directory as `bar.xml` is? Or am I misunderstanding?

Comment: You understand well. All the `_tpl` files are in the same directory the makefile is. And I'm trying to write a rule that will match `foo.xml`, `path/to/foo.xml`, `../ressources/foo.xml` and so on. But as I think of it, I begin to believe it is just too far from how make is supposed to work and I should rethink the whole structure of what I'm doing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you always want the targets in another directory, just say so.

```
TARGETS:=$(patsubst %_tpl,../resources/%,$(wildcard *_tpl))

.PHONY: all
all: $(TARGETS)

.SECONDEXPANSION:
$(TARGETS): ../resources/%: $$(wildcard %*_tpl)
    ./generate $@_tpl > $@
```

I'm not sure if you should have `generate $^ >$@` instead; superficially, this would make more sense.

If there are multiple `*_tpl` files for each target (i.e. there are more `tpl` files than `xml` files), the `TARGETS` definition isn't really correct; but we don't have enough information to actually fix it.

On the other hand, if the target directory can change a lot, the sane way forward might be to `cd` into the target directory and use `make -f ../path/to/Makefile` -- just make sure your `VPATH` is set up so that the source files can be found.

Comment: That works, thanks. the `TARGETS` definition is correct: each target has a main template (`$@_tpl`) that includes others (`$@-part1_tpl`, `$@-part2_tpl`...) and the `generate` script only takes the main template as argument. I upvoted your answer but will wait to see if there is a way to avoid explicitly specifying `../ressources/` as a possible destination folder befor accepting it. Thanks anyway! That helped.

Comment: You could also just parametrize the directory name; `TARGETS:=$(patsubst %_tpl,$(TARGETDIR)/%,$(wildcard *_tpl))` and invoke it with `make TARGETDIR=../resources` (you obviously need to change the rest to use the same variable).

Comment: Your current `TARGETS` definitions is not correct then; it will (eventually) try to make `foo-part1` as well as `foo`.  If the pattern is regular, it won't be very hard to fix it.

Comment: It won't try to make `foo-part1` since it already exists and doesn't have any dependency. Or am I missing something? I'll look at the `make -f` idea with `VPATH`, but right now I think it could be overly complicated since the `generate` script won't be called from the correct working directory (I'll see if there is a way to cleanly `cd` before invoking it).

Comment: In the end, the ability to generate a file to an arbitrary directory is too unnatural and not important enough (I have really few possible target directories, and no file is really needed at two different locations). Thanks again for your answer!