# makefile select prerequisites depending on source

Tags: makefile

Suppose I have the following files:

```
.:           include/  01.src  02.src  03.src  Makefile

./include:   01.inc  02-source1.inc  02-source2.inc
```

for which I have the following Makefile (source: [Complex pattern rule in Makefile](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26672148/2174266)):

```
exe = ${patsubst %.src, %.exe, ${wildcard *.src}}

all : ${exe}

.SECONDEXPANSION:
${exe} : %.exe : %.src $${wildcard include/%*.inc}
    @echo compile $@ using $^
```

This says that `01.exe` will be compiled using `01.src` and `include/01*.inc` (something similar for `02.exe` and `03.exe`). In fact, make outputs:

```
compile 01.exe using 01.src include/01.inc
compile 02.exe using 02.src include/02-source1.inc include/02-source2.inc
compile 03.exe using 03.src
```

**My question is: How should I modify this Makefile if `01.src`, `02.src`, and `03.src` are renamed to `01-first.src`, `02-second.src`, and `03-third.src`?** The desired output is:

```
compile 01-first.exe using 01-first.src include/01.inc
compile 02-second.exe using 02-second.src include/02-source1.inc include/02-source2.inc
compile 03-third.exe using 03-third.src
```

Comment: Is someone else imposing that hideous naming convention on you?

Comment: Yes. Although the project is a bit large, I'm open to suggestions ;)

Comment: **Be very careful about showing that you're smarter than your boss.** Comply with the rules imposed on you, but see what improvements you can make safely. For instance, if you create symbolic links (with sensible names) to the source files, your makefile will be much simpler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
${exe} : %.exe : %.src $${wildcard include/$$(shell echo % | head -c 2)*.inc}
    @echo compile $@ using $^
```

*output:*

```
compile 03-third.exe using 03-third.src
compile 02-second.exe using 02-second.src include/02-source1.inc include/02-source2.inc
compile 01-first.exe using 01-first.src include/01.inc
```